# glscalef effect on normal vectors

Tags: opengl, graphics, rendering, scale, mesh

So I have a .3ds mesh that I imported into my project and it's quite large so I wanted to scale it down in size using glscalef. However the rendering algorithm I use in my shader makes use of normal vector values and so after scaling my rendering algorithm no longer works exactly as it should. So how do remedy this? Is there a glscalef for normals as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Normal vectors are transformed by the transposed inverse of the modelview matrix](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Illumination/Tut09%20Normal%20Transformation.html). However a second constraint is, that normals be of unit length and scaling the modelview changes that. So in your shader, you should apply a normalization step

```
#version 330

uniform mat4x4 MV;
uniform mat4x4 P;
uniform mat4x4 N; // = transpose(inv(MV));

in vec3 vertex_pos;    // vertes position attribute
in vec3 vertex_normal; // vertex normal attribute

out vec3 trf_normal;

void main()
{
    trf_normal = normalize( (N * vec4(vertex_normal, 1)).xyz );
    gl_Position = P * MV * vertex_pos;
}
```

*Note that "normalization" is the process of turning a vector into colinear vector of its own with unit length, and has nothing to do with the concept of surface normals.*

Comment: So in my shader I already have the code:     

normal = (gl_NormalMatrix * normalIn).xyz; where normalIn is my passed in normal and 'normal' is what gets sent to the fragment shader. 

So I should not use the built in gl_NormalMatrix at all then? I sort of assumed (erroneously I guess) that gl_NormalMatrix would update itself internally to compensate for my scaling.

Comment: @user1782677: gl_NormalMatrix is just tranpose(inv(gl_ModelviewMatrix)) and nothing more. You can use it, but you must add that normalization step, i.e. write `normal = normalize( (gl_NormalMatrix * normalIn).xyz );` Omitting the w-component is important, as this would throw of the length calculation of the normal vector.

Answer (score 0):

To transform normals, you need to multiply them by the **inverse transpose of the transformation matrix**. There are several explanations of why this is the case, the best one is probably [here](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Illumination/Tut09%20Normal%20Transformation.html)

Answer (score 0):

Normal is transformed by MV^IT, the inverse transpose of the modelview matrix, read the redbook, it explains everything.